# AWS Pinpoint envio de sms

Tags: aws, aws-sdk-java

**Hola a todos y gracias por adelantado por la ayuda.**

Estoy con el tema de AWS, para enviar mensajes cortos con un código de confirmación para luego operar desde la web a efectos de cofirmar números de teléfono para un sistema de registro.

El caso es que dentro de Pinpoint genero el proyecto, doy permisos de SMS y todo correcto.

Luego voy a Lambda para generar con Python el script con la información que pongo a continuación :

```
# Adapted from https://docs.aws.amazon.com/pinpoint/latest/developerguide/send-messages-sms.html
# Disclaimer: this is sample code for demonstration purposes only

import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError

# The AWS Region that you want to use to send the message. For a list of
# AWS Regions where the Amazon Pinpoint API is available, see
# https://docs.aws.amazon.com/pinpoint/latest/apireference/
region = "us-east-1"

# The recipient's phone number.  For best results, you should specify the
# phone number in E.164 format.
destinationNumber = "+34xxxxxxxxx"

# The content of the SMS message.
message = ("This is a sample message sent from Amazon Pinpoint by using the "
           "AWS SDK for Python (Boto 3).")

# The Amazon Pinpoint project/application ID to use when you send this message.
# Make sure that the SMS channel is enabled for the project or application
# that you choose.
applicationId = "756eb65350354ea19db68ac654d76fa8"

# The type of SMS message that you want to send. If you plan to send
# time-sensitive content, specify TRANSACTIONAL. If you plan to send
# marketing-related content, specify PROMOTIONAL.
messageType = "TRANSACTIONAL"


# Create a new client and specify a region.
client = boto3.client('pinpoint',region_name=region)
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    try:
        response = client.send_messages(
            ApplicationId=applicationId,
            MessageRequest={
                'Addresses': {
                    destinationNumber: {
                        'ChannelType': 'SMS'
                    }
                },
                'MessageConfiguration': {
                    'SMSMessage': {
                        'Body': message,
                        'MessageType': messageType
                    }
                }
            }
        )
    
    except ClientError as e:
        print(e.response['Error']['Message'])
    else:
        print("Message sent! Message ID: "
                + response['MessageResponse']['Result'][destinationNumber]['MessageId'])
```

**El caso es que al principio - y sigue igual - no funcionaba y solo me ponía en la consola esto :**

```
User: arn:aws:sts::753872362211:assumed-role/Test-sms-new-role-vegr03n9/Test-sms-new is not authorized to perform: mobiletargeting:SendMessages on resource: arn:aws:mobiletargeting:us-east-1:753872362211:apps/756eb65350354ea19db68ac654d76fa8/messages
```

He ido a Roles, busco el tema de la función Lambda y le doy a la sección correspondiente buscando pinpoint, pero solo me sale esta :

**pinpoint-email-ers-**

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "mobileanalytics:PutItems",
                "mobileanalytics:PutEvents"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

He intentado crear una política nueva y no me salen los recursos necesarios, no sé si es porque estoy en Sandbox o qué, el caso es que no hay manera y como en AWS está todo muy "explicado" pues ya no sé que más hacer, llevo ya un montón con esto y no hay forma, a ver si me podéis decir cual es el error porque no sé que más mirar la verdad.

**Un saludo.**